# Routing for editing/update individual model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-attributes

I have a User model and a ProfileQuestionnaire model. A User has_one ProfileQuestionnaire, and each ProfileQuestionnaire has five questions (that the user has answered) as attributes.

The users#edit action shows the set of five ProfileQuestionnaire questions that the User has answered. My question is: assuming each of the questions has an "Edit" button next to it on this users#edit view, how do I modify my routes (shown below) to make it possible for this "Edit" button to direct the user to an action dedicated to a specific question for editing and updating? That is, for editing/updating a specific attribute on the ProfileQuestionnaire model one at a time?

```
  resources :users do
    resources :profile_questionnaires
  end
```

Comment: Can you post routes for questions, too? Also, view code where you display edit link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Nested Resources**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

You'd do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do 
   resources :profile_questionnaires #-> domain.com/users/:user_id/profile_questionnaires/:id
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% @user.profile_questionnaires.each do |question| %>
   <%= link_to question.name, user_profile_questionnaire_path(@user, question), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

This will take you to the `profile_questionnaires#edit` action, which you'll have to then work with yourself:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_questionnaires_controller.rb
class ProfilesQuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = User.find params[:user_id] if params[:user_id].present?
      @profile_questionnaire = ProfileQuestionnaire.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

---

**Attribute**

In order to change specific attributes in your `ProfileQuestionnaire` model, you want to remember that there is no inbuilt way to achieve this in Rails - you'll just need to be able to create a form with a single attribute in there.

As there is a lack of context, I'll have to assume that you want to *manually* change the attribute. The way I'd do it personally is to keep it all in the `edit` view, and use some conditional statements to determine whether what to show:

```
#app/views/profiles_questionnaires/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for [@user, @profile_questionnaire] do |f| %>
   <% %w(your params here).each do |param| %>
      <%= f.text_field param.to_s if @type.include?(param.to_s) %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

> - Your controller doesn't care which params it is sent
> - You can stipulate the attribute you wish to show / edit
> - It gives you the ability to extend the functionality

Here's how you'll manage the controller:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_questionnaires_controller.rb
class ProfilesQuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = User.find [:user_id]
      @profile_questionnaire = ProfileQuestionnaire.find params[:id]

      @type = params[:type] if params[:type].present?
      @type ||= ProfileQuestionnaire.column_names
   end
end
```

You'd then be able to send the following link to the controller:

```
<%= link_to "x", user_profiles_questionnaire_path(@user, "4", type: "param_1" %>
```